# SSL context override vulnerability on Django-rest serializer

Tags: django, security, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, owasp

I have HCL AppScan CodeSweep installed on VScode and it picked up an SSL context vulnerability on one of my Django serializers and I was just wondering I can go about fixing it without changing my desired functionality.

```
class CategoryDetailSerializer(CategoryListSerializer):
products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = (
        'id',
        'title',
        'products',
    )

def get_products(self, obj):
    # The source of the SSL context override
    return ProductListSerializer(obj.product_set.all(), many=True, context=self.context).data

class ProductListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name='products:product-detail-view', lookup_field='slug')

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = (
        'id',
        'slug',
        'title',
        'price',
        'image',
        'url',
    )
```

Comment: Could you add a few lines of code after this snippet? I reckon the tool is reporting on something further on.

Comment: I've added the next line but here is the link to the whole file: https://github.com/Sugar-Hill/nf-kicks-api/blob/master/app/products/serializers.py

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a real issue, but what is known as a noise or a false positive. You can mark it as noise in the tool and it will not show up again in future scans.